# How to calculate LCM for natural numbers 1 to N in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, modulo

So, my question is to find the smallest multiple that divides evenly into all numbers from 1 through 20. I did solve the task successfully, but my program ran rather slow. Here is the code, the final number for n i used was 100 million.
As you can imagine, that takes a lot of time. So I wanted to know, how i would optimize this code?
Additionally, it would be nice to know how to change the number of numbers it should divide into, so instead of 1 through 20 let's say 1 through 15.

```
function smallestMultiple(n) {
    for (i = 0; i< n; i++) {
        if (i%1 === 0 && i%2 === 0 && i%3 === 0 && i%4 === 0 && i%5 === 0 
                 && i%6 === 0 && i%7 === 0 && i%8 === 0 && i%9 === 0 
                 && i%10 === 0 && i%11 === 0 && i%12 === 0 && i%13 === 0 
                 && i%14 === 0 && i%15 === 0 && i%16 === 0 && i%17 === 0 
                 && i%18 === 0 && i%19 === 0 && i%20 === 0 ) {

            console.log(i);
        }
    };
};
```

Now, obviously, this took over 5 minutes to find the answer. I wanted to know if there was a way more efficient way?
EDIT: Obviously i could have used a variable for 1-20 as well. Will look into that, if you have an answer please thoroughly explain your answer and why it is more efficient.

Comment: `lcm(1, lcm(2, lcm(3, ...)))`, where `lcm` is the least common multiple.

Comment: Take your biggest number (in this case 20) and change your for like this: `for (i = 0; i< n; i +=20 ) `

Comment: You should break out of the `for` loop when you find the first successful number.

Comment: You don't have to check the modulo for any non-prime numbers - `%18` is redundant because when `i%9 == 0` we already know that `i%(9*2) == 0`

Comment: You don't need to test against all the numbers that are multiples of each other. If `n` is a multiple of 20, then it's also a multiple of all its factors, so you don't need to test 2, 4, 5, and 10.

Comment: All of the above are each good time savers compared to your approach. Few of them may be not trivial to implement, specially what @Barmar says (given an arbitrary number n for a range length 1... n).

Comment: Correct answer is `232792560`

Comment: I think you should edit the question's title to have it say "javascript"

Answer (score 6):

I think I found one of the most elegant solutions, straight from the forum:

> Without actually trying it, I imagine that a few of the "brute force"
>   methods here violate the "1 minute rule".  However, considering a
>   minor change can greatly improve the efficiency of the algorithm.
>
> The "brute force" approach is assumed to be: iterate over each natural
>   number - if the current is evenly divisible by each of the numbers 1
>   through 20, you've found your answer.
>
> Consider this: if you know that the solution for N is X, then the
>   solution for N+1 must be divisible by X.  Therefore, when iterating
>   through the natural numbers, you can iterate by X instead of 1.  And
>   instead of checking for the divisibility of the numbers 1 to N+1, you
>   only have to check for N+1, since you already know that the values
>   (multiples of X) are all divisible by 1 to N.
>
> As an example, given that the answer for 10 is 2520, to get the
>   solution of 11, we check if 2520 is evenly divisible by 11.  It isn't,
>   we iterate to 5040 and check if that is divisible by 11.  We continue
>   until we discover that 27720 is divisible by 11, which is out answer.
>
> Despite making no attempt to directly determine LCDs, this ends up
>   being a fairly speedy algorithm, running easily under a second for
>   somewhat larger values of N.
>
> In Ruby (though a similar approach can be used in many high-level
>   languages):
>
> def snd(max)   result = 1   for n in 1..max
>       prev = result
>       while result % n > 0
>         result += prev
>       end   end   return result end
>
> puts snd(20)

I then interpreted that into Javascript and got this script

```js
console.log("Please type in smallestMultiple(n), whereas n is the smallest multiple.");

function smallestMultiple(n) {
   var result = 1;
   var prev;
   for (i=1; i<n+1; i++) {
       prev = result;
       while (result%i > 0) {
           result += prev;
       }
   }
   console.log(result);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Found an error in the script that would return `smallestNumber(11)` = 2520. Fixed in the `for` loop: for(i=0; i<**n+1** ;i++)

Comment: Now _this_ is elegant.

Comment: This is awesome. It's like it gets exponentially faster as you get closer to the answer.

Comment: `smallestMultiple(11) == 2520`, `2520/11 == 229.0909090909091`?

Comment: And I might add, as you already have n(11)= 27720, you no longer need n(10) because you know that all previous numbers are evenly divisible. So you iterate n(11) until you find that the smallest multiple for n(13) is still 27720, but n(14) isn't. so, add up your n(13) + n(13), 
you get 55440, 73160...etc. until you reach 360360 which is indeed the LCM of 14.

Comment: @dave I fixed it as you can see. now it works. if any other errors pop up, let me know.

Comment: If the answer comes "straight from the forum", please provide a link in your answer. Was it this? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/problem-5-on-project-euler

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain the relevant link.

Answer (score 3):

Using the method of [reduction by the greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)

Skipping numbers 1 - 10 because you can multiply any of them by 2 and get another factor in the list.

```
function GCF(a, b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    else return (GCF (b, a % b));
}

function LCM(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a*b) / GCF(a, b);
}

LCM(11, LCM(12, LCM(13, LCM(14, LCM(15, LCM(16, LCM(17, LCM(18, LCM(19, 20)))))))));
```

To do it for an arbitrary n, not super optimized but it is as simple as:

```
function LCM_N(n) {
    var x = 1;
    while (n > 1) {
        x = LCM(n, x);
        n--;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I would like to see just how long this gets for an arbitrary range length instead of 20.

Comment: This is the best way to do it.

Comment: LCM_N is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the least common multiple of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

This is the same as the least common multiple (LCM) of 20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11 because 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are all factors of the other ten numbers.

You should use a while loop, because they are faster.

The LCM must be less than or equal to the multiple of 20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11, so `n` can be started equal to that.

`i` can be started at the multiple of all of the primes in the sequence: 19*17*13*11*7*5*3*2

`break` out of the loop. This is probably what made it take so long for you.

We can increment by 20, because it is the smallest possible difference between answers.

```
function lowestCommonMultipleof20Through1(){
  var i = 19*17*13*11*7*5*4*3; 
  var n = 20*19*18*17*16*15*14*13*12*11;
  while(i < n){
    if( i%11 === 0 && 
        i%12 === 0 && 
        i%13 === 0 && 
        i%14 === 0 && 
        i%15 === 0 && 
        i%16 === 0 &&
        i%17 === 0 &&
        i%18 === 0 &&
        i%19 === 0 &&
        i%20 === 0 ){
      console.log(i);
      break;
    }
    i+=20;
  }
}
```

I got 232792560 almost instantly.